# How to pass parameters from viewmodel to viewmodel in wph8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

How to pass and get the parameters from one viewmodel to another viewmodel in wph8.1 i am using INavigationService like below but i don't know how to get the parameters from another viewmodel.

```
  _Navigate.Navigate(typeof(nextView),data);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `Messenger` to pass data between the view-models. Messenger is intented for it.

To send a message:

```
MessengerInstance.Send(payload, token);
```

To receive message

```
MessengerInstance.Register<PayloadType>(
this, token, payload => SomeAction(payload));
```

**View model 1**

```
MessengerInstance.Send(Brushes.Red, MessengerToken.BrushChanged);
```

**View Model 2**

```
class ViewModel()
{
 // put this line in the constructor
  MessengerInstance.Register<Brush>(this, token, brush => ChangeColor(brush))
}

//Receive here 
public void ChangeColor(Brush brush)
{
  Brush = brush;
}
```